# No encuentro el tipo correcto para un parametro de Typescript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, type

tengo el siguiente codigo:

export default class Cliente extends Model {}

```
Cliente.init(
  {
    id_cliente: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    nombre_cliente: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    apellido_cliente: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    telefono_cliente: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    id_sucursal: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    numero_de_cuenta: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize: bd,
    tableName: 'cliente',
  }
);
```

Cree un modelo de datos con sequelize. funciona todo perfecto con su interfaz.
ahora quiero crear una funcion que pasandole 3 parametros, 2 Modelos y un string, me arme una relacion esto seria asi:

```
function agregaRelacion(m1: any, m2: any, fk: String) {
  m1.hasOne(m2, { foreignKey: fk });
  m2.hasOne(m1, { foreignKey: fk });
}
```

esto funciona el tema esta en que no se que tipo pasar a "m1" para que funcione sin la "trampa" de poner any.
probé de muchas manera y nada funciona.
Use Model que lo importe de sequelize correctamente , y tampoco funciono.

Comment: En todo caso `m1` y `m2` son de tipo `Cliente` cierto?

Comment: si uno si, el otro tendría que ser de otra clase. pero también hereda de Model.Osea que si funciona en Cliente funciona para cualquiera.